# TypeError: 'kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy' object is not callable Kivi

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, kivy, kivy-language

I'm new to kivy, and I'm to write a `viewer` app.
Currently I'm working on the design alone, but I'm getting the following error:
`line 239, in create_view 
view_instance = cls(**item_args) TypeError: 'kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy' object is not callable`

Sharing my code:

**bins_player.py:**

```
import kivy
import glob
from os import path
import tkinter as tk
from kivy.app import App
from tkinter import filedialog
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

kivy.require('1.9.0')

class FilesPanel(GridLayout):
    frames_list = ObjectProperty()

    def open_files(self):
        root = tk.Tk()
        root.withdraw()

        self.load_files(filedialog.askdirectory(parent=root,initialdir="/", title='Please select a directory'))

    def load_files(self, selected_folder):
        all_bin_files = glob.glob(path.join(selected_folder, '*.bin'))

        for bin_file in all_bin_files:
            self.frames_list.adapter.data.extend([bin_file])
            self.frames_list._trigger_reset_populate()


class BinsPlayerMain(GridLayout):
    pass


class Bins_PlayerApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.title = 'Bins Player'
        self.icon = 'BinsPlayer.ico'
        return BinsPlayerMain()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Bins_PlayerApp().run()
```

**bins_player.kv:**

```
#: include ui/filespanel.kv

<BinsPlayerMain>:
    rows: 2

    GridLayout:
```

**filespanel.kv:**

```
#: include force ui/sectiontitle.kv
#: import ListAdapter kivy.adapters.listadapter.ListAdapter

<FilesPanel>:
        id: filesPanel
        frames_list: frames_list_view
        rows: 2
        size_hint_x:  None
        width: 200

        ListView:
                id: frames_list_view
                rgba: .2, .2, .2, 1
                adapter:
                        ListAdapter(data=[], cls=filesPanel)

        Button:
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 30
                spacing: 10
                text: 'Open Folder'
                on_press: filesPanel.open_files()
```

I'm getting this error right after I'm opening a folder - after the `ListView` gets updated.

What could be the problem here?

I saw a `new` layout called `ResycleView` - can this be used here instead of the `ListView`?

Comment: the `cls` parameter in your `filespanel.kv` should be a class, but you are passing a `kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy` (that is what the `id` `filesPanel1` actually is).

Comment: Then I should pass the `FilesPanel` class instead? If I do that I get an error `NameError: name 'FilesPanel' is not defined`

Comment: No `FilesPanel` is not the class you want. The `cls` parameter is a class that will be used to display each element in the `ListView`. A simple one is `ListItemLabel`. And yes, you can use `RecycleView`, in fact, `ListView` is deprecated in favor of `RecycleView`. See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.listview.html#listadapter-and-dictadapter).